# Why do editors sometimes reject manuscripts for being out of scope even though they cite references from the same journal?

Tags: publications, editors, elsevier

I wonder why editors sometimes do reject  submitted manuscripts for being out of the journal's scopes while the authors have utilized published papers from the same journals.

Is it just a polite way of rejection?

Comment: Journals can have all kinds of scopes, so there could be many reasons.  A methods themed journal, for example, would not be suitable for most of the papers that cite the journal because they use the methods found in the journal but do not develop new methods.

Comment: Consider a recent paper I wrote about Ebola control - it cites a number of papers from computational chemistry journals. Is there a reason to think it's *in scope* for those journals?

Comment: Some answers to these closely related questions apply here: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/17942/19607 and http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/43012/19607

Comment: I'm not able to parse this question. What are "the same journals"?

Comment: _I wonder why editors sometimes do reject submitted manuscripts for being out of the journal's scopes while the authors have utilized published papers from the same journals._ — I'm going to take a wild guess here, but, possibly, because citing a million articles from the same journal doesn't guarantee in-scope-ness of a manuscript?

Answer (score 19):

Cape Code has given a good answer, but it's not the only possibility for such a rejection.  Suppose you publish a paper in, say, "Topology and Its Applications", in which you prove some topological result using (among other things) a set-theoretic lemma. And suppose I later prove some result in algebra using (among other things) your lemma.  Of course, I would cite your paper, but that doesn't put my algebra paper into the scope of "Topology and Its Applications".

Answer (score 8):

Citing articles form a given journal does not automatically mean your paper is in its scope.

Even if the subject and methodology of your work seem similar to the ones of the articles in a given journal, the scope can also include quality criteria. As an example, Nature Chemistry, in the [description of its scope](http://www.nature.com/nchem/authors/aims_scope.html) says:

> Nature Chemistry is committed to publishing **top-tier** original research in all areas of chemistry [...]

Or, some journals decide to accept only papers based on their impact potential. If we look at the New England Journal of Medicine, the [scope description](https://cdf.nejm.org/misc/authors/) states:

> We are interested in original research that will **change clinical practice** or **teach us something new** about the biology of disease.

etc.

Comment: I do agree. However, we have faced it differently. I helped my colleague to prepare his paper according to the journal's scope and we found the objective of his work in some published papers from the same journal (the one we submitted our manuscript).

Comment: @user34526: Then you have other (much more important) reasons than the cited papers to argue that your paper is on scope. Those may all be very justified but that’s not what you have been asking about.

Comment: @user34526 What about the methods used to achieve the objective. Are they different enough to justify that the older papers are in the scope of the journal, but your new paper is not?

Comment: @ Wrzlprmft: Exactly

Comment: @ DCTLib: Well... The methodology was quite the same as practiced by previous researchers, however, the material used in his study was totally new and he got new results in his field of study.

Comment: I'm not saying his work was perfect but whatever it was, It wasn't out of the journal's scope for sure.

Comment: We would really appreciate it if the editor could directly tell us the problem. That's what I'm expecting

Comment: @user34526 *It wasn't out of the journal's scope for sure* Well apparently the editor disagrees. And it's her/his call. Editors are free to reject papers without giving specific reasons. While it is true that it is not particularly useful to you, there is not much you can do about it. Just submit somewhere else.

Comment: @Cape Code: The paper is published now. I'm trying to understand the policy which is practiced in different journals. BTW, thanks for sharing your opinion.

Comment: I wonder how "teach us something new about [the field of the journal]" differs from almost every journal's requirement that papers contain novel research...

Comment: @DavidRicherby the new trend in fashionable journals seems to answer your question: "[The world’s first multidisciplinary Open Access journal, PLOS ONE accepts scientifically rigorous research, regardless of novelty.](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/s/journal-information)"

Answer (score 6):

One of the most common cases for being out of scope for the journal in such a case is that the paper is not at the right level of the theory-practice scale.

In particular, an application paper can make use of a lot of concepts of earlier theoretical work. Yet, that doesn't meant that the application paper is in scope. If the readership of the journal most likely does not understand the details of the application that are needed to understand the paper, then this is a good reason for rejection.

Likewise, for a theory paper, the problem studied may be well-motivated by practice. Yet, if the novel result builds on concepts that are out-of-scope for the rather practical journal, then the paper is also likely to be rejected.

Answer (score 6):

I'll add another example to the several already given. There are a number of journals (e.g. some or many of the *Letters on...*) which have a somewhat fast review process, in order to publish results on "hot topics" in a relatively short time.

However, to publish in those kind of journals, not only does your work have to be on-topic, original, innovative, etc. (the usual stuff), but you should also justify the need for such a fast publication track.

Now, even if you produce an original high-quality work with the aim of publishing in such a journal, and even if your paper is apparently within its scope (and even citing references from that same journal), you might have worked on a topic which was hot ten years ago but now barely warm, and your paper would definitely fall out of scope.